# Convert ImageBitmap to Blob

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I'm using createImageBitmap() which creates an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) file.

How do I convert this file to a blob or ideally PNG so I can upload?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer to make it use bitmaprenderer context. Was silly to not mention it in the first rev....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only way currently is to draw it on a canvas.

For more efficiency, you can try to use an [ImageBitmapRenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext), which will **not** copy the pixels buffer again.

```js
(async () => {

  const resp = await fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png');
  // yes.. from a Blob to a Blob...
  const blob1 = await resp.blob();
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob1);
  console.log(bmp); // ImageBitmap
  // create a canvas
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  // resize it to the size of our ImageBitmap
  canvas.width = bmp.width;
  canvas.height = bmp.height;
  // get a bitmaprenderer context
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('bitmaprenderer');
  ctx.transferFromImageBitmap(bmp);
  // get it back as a Blob
  const blob2 = await new Promise((res) => canvas.toBlob(res));
  console.log(blob2); // Blob
  const img = document.body.appendChild(new Image());
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob2);
  
})().catch(console.error);
```

Check [HTMLCanvasElement#toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) for the options you can pass in (file format and quality when applicable).

Comment: That really helps but for some reason I'm getting an empty image out.. I've put it into a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960102/createimagebitmap-returns-an-empty-image

Comment: For reference, I believe this is now fixed in Chrome.