# createImageBitmap returns an empty image

Tags: javascript, image

I'm using createImageBitmap to convert an image in a worker.

The blob goes in has data, the positioning is valid (they're minus numbers but I've tried using 0 and same issue)

```
 createImageBitmap(blob, -pos.x + 100, -pos.y + 100, 200, 200).then(data => {
            resolve(data)})
```

The data that comes out is `<ImageData width: 200, height 200 />`

However when then try and convert this into a blob

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      canvas.height = img.height
      canvas.width = img.width
      const context = canvas.getContext('bitmaprenderer')
      context.transferFromImageBitmap(img)

canvas.toBlob((blob)=> ..
```

The blob is empty.

Any clues on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: They can be zeros. The first blob is coming from a large image generated in aframe (webGL), I'm passing it to a worker to do the image processing and resize because it's beeen freezing the browser. 

The first blob is valid, with data. It console logs as having lots of data. I've tried with pos.x and y = 0 and no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=838108) with the bitmaprenderer context...

For whatever reason, the result of `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()` and `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()` will be fully transparent images...

They don't honor the current active bitmap-buffer that is displayed in the HTMLCanvasElement.

This can be demonstrated by appending the canvas to the document:

```js
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png')
  .then(r => r.blob())
  .then(b=>createImageBitmap(b, 120,120,120,120))
  .then(img => {
    return new Promise(res => {
      // create a canvas
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      // resize it to the size of our ImageBitmap
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      document.body.append(canvas);
      // transfer on the bitmarenderer context
      canvas.getContext('bitmaprenderer')
        .transferFromImageBitmap(img);
      // get it back as a Blob
      canvas.toBlob(res);
    });
  })
  .then(blob => {
    var img = document.body.appendChild(new Image());
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  });
```

```css
img {
  border: solid red;
}
canvas {
  border: solid green;
}
```

You can star [the issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=838108) so that it gets higher priority, and for te time being you might want to fallback to a 2dContext and its memory draining *drawImage()* method...

```js
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png')
  .then(r => r.blob())
  .then(b=>createImageBitmap(b, 120,120,120,120))
  .then(img => {
    return new Promise(res => {
      // create a canvas
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      // resize it to the size of our ImageBitmap
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      document.body.append(canvas);
      // draw on a 2d context
      canvas.getContext('2d')
        .drawImage(img,0,0);
      // get it back as a Blob
      canvas.toBlob(res);
    });
  })
  .then(blob => {
    var img = document.body.appendChild(new Image());
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  });
```

```css
img {
  border: solid red;
}
canvas {
  border: solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido - you're very helpful.